# c++ array index calculation issues

Tags: c++

Sorry for this simple question, but I can't solve it...

There is an example:

```
int a[10] = {6, 7.8, 8.0, -6, -5.7, 5, 5.7};

std::cout << a[6 % 8 / 4 + 21 % 9];
```

In response I get **-5**, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Also, using parentheses in your `a[...]` expression will improve the readability of your code and prevent unintended order of operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
Operators have their priority so in this case: 6 % 8 / 4 + 21 % 9 = (((6%8)/4)+(21%9))=(6/4)+(3)=4

```
a[0]=6,
a[1]=(int)7.8 = 7, (correct me if i'm wrong)
a[2] = (int)8.0 = 8,
a[3] = -6,
a[4] = (int)-5.7 = -5,
a[5] = 5,
a[6] = (int)5.7 = 5
```

So element with index 4 it's -5.7 casted to integer gives -5 (the rest is just cut off)

Answer (score 7):

because your array is a integer array.

you should use at first

```
float a[10]
```

Answer (score 2):

`6 % 8 / 4 => (6%8) / 4 => 6 / 4 => (int)1.5 => 1` (6/4 is int -- num and denom are ints)
`21 % 9 => 3`
`1 + 3 == 4`

`a[4] == (int)(-5.7) == 5`

`a` is an `int` array and so the numbers there are int's and not floats.
index 4 is chosen because of [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Doesn't C++ use integer division by default so there would never be a "1.5" but just "1" instead?

Comment: @AustinSalonen the result of the division is "1". I wrote the stage of `(int)1.5` so that the op would understand why it's actually 1 (because of trunc) and not 1.5. hope I didn't confuse

Comment: ok, thanks. best explanation (but I think -5) correct? :) thanks again.